# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in jwplayer script

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, http, jwplayer

I am new here .
I have a problem in Access-Control-Allow-Origin .

Here is my script

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Max TV Bangla | Live (Test Transmission)</title>



<!-- JW Player Library -->
<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/T321vYRO.js"></script>


</head>

<body style="background: #2f3542;">

<div align="center">
    <div style="width: 75%; padding:5px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 30px; font-weight: bold;">
        Max TV Bangla | Live (Test Transmission)
    </div>
    <div style="width: 75%; height: 100%; padding: 5px;">
        <!-- div for the player -->
        <div id='playerKXSDPIwKERSv'></div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>




<!-- Script to display video file in the player div -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('playerKXSDPIwKERSv').setup({
        // URL to the video file
        file: 'http://103.106.237.73:8080/hls/maxtvbangla.m3u8',
        //http://103.106.237.73:8080/hls/maxtvbangla.m3u8
        //https://ssh101.com/m3u8/dyn/maxtvbangla/index.m3u8
        // URL to the image that should be shown before the video is started
        image: 'http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/sB0jqeIC-720.jpg',
        title: 'Max TV Bangla | Live (Test Transmission)',
        width: '100%',
        aspectratio: '16:9'
    });
</script>

</html>
```

I got Failed to load http://103.106.237.73:8080/hls/maxtvbangla.m3u8: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://expertitbd.com' is therefore not allowed access from console .

Live link is : http://expertitbd.com/MAXTVLIVE/index.php

I want to solution about this issue why I faced this problem .
Its about jwplayer ...

Thanks 
Max

Comment: That `103.106.237.73` domain is where the access control headers need to be set, not your own domain.

Comment: okk I will try sir :)

Comment: I checked the 103.106.237.73 its enable the access control headers . I think the problem in the player section

Comment: You should be able to see what's going on in the browser "Network" developer tool. That will show you all the details about the outgoing HTTP requests and the site responses.